# coreui- how to change styling of the template?

Tags: html, css, core-ui

I am using CoreUi template for my laravel project and as I am unfamiliar with this, I heard it is not good to override the their classes if I want to change the styling of the template, enhance it,etc.

Below is an image of the template:

[image]

Can anyone advice in which file do I need to alter if I want to mess with color, fonts, etc?

Comment: Hi! I am using the same template. I would like to change the theme color to green and change the logo too. Can you please suggest me how to solve the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change scss variables in _variables.scss file.

Full documentation can be found here: https://coreui.io/docs/